# Using Angularjs with server side templates

Tags: javascript, angularjs

For SEO purposes the server renders out the full html template for a given URL on initial load. The site uses angularjs which detects the URL route and renders a client template from the JSON API.

For example, you navigate to: **/blog/post-title**

Server responds with **post-title** content. Angular loads, detects route: **/blog/:post_slug** and begins to load JSON and render client side template from response.

Obviously what Angular does is fine when links are followed **after** the initial load, but on first load it duplicates effort.

My question is if there is a clean way to prevent this situation.

Comment: I think I understand the question enough to say that nothing prevents you from generating the templates dynamically when angularjs requests them.